# How to set a storyboard as first view

Tags: ios, xcode, ipados

J'ai créer un storyboard et je ne trouve pas comment l'afficher sur Simulator

I created a storyboard and I can’t find how to display it in Simulator.

Comment: Would be good to ask in English. To display a storyboard you need an app that use storyboard at its start point.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new project with storyboards selected, it automatically displays "Main.storyboard" after your app loads.

You can set the name of the storyboard to load inside the info.plist. It's now moved to:

Application Scene Manifest -> Scene Configuration -> -> -> Storyboard name

[image]